# Insert radiobutton value into MS Access database as boolean data type

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, insert

I am trying to insert values from a form into a MS Access database. I am getting an error for "datatype mismatch" on the radio buttons. I know the error is with the radio buttons because if I take them out, the form works fine. I have 3 radio buttons and a Boolean column for each in hopes that the one that is checked returns true and the other 2 return false.

```
   Dim myquery As String = "insert into [dbo_tblCoachtheCoach] ([Coach],[CoachID],[Manager],[ManagerID],[Supv],[SupvID],[OneonOne],[FollowUp],[Other],[Date],[Time],[Rev_Prep],[Engage],[SelfDiscovery],[SMART_Goals],[Results],[Coach_Goal],[Notes]) values (@Coach,@CoachID,@Manager,@MangerID,@Supv,@SupvID,@OneonOne,@FollowUp,@Other,@Date,@Time,@RevPrep,@Engage,@SelfDiscovery,@SmartGoals,@Results,@Goals,@Notes)"



        Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand
        With cmd
            .CommandText = myquery
            .Connection = newScoreConn

            'inserting data into tblCoachtheCoach
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@Coach", cmbCoach.SelectedItem)
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@CoachID", txtCoach.Text)
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@Manager", cmbManager.SelectedItem)
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@MangerID", txtManager.Text)
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@Supv", cmbSupv.SelectedItem)
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@SupvID", txtSupv.Text)


            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", DateTimePicker1.Text)
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@Time", txtTime.Text)

            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@OneonOne", radioOne.Checked)
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@FollowUp", radioFollow.Checked)
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@Other", radioOther.Checked)

            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@RevPrep", cmbRevPrep.SelectedItem)
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@Engage", cmbEngage.SelectedItem)
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@SelfDiscovery", cmbSelfDiscovery.SelectedItem)
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@SmartGoals", cmbSmartGoals.SelectedItem)
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@Results", cmbResults.SelectedItem)

            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@Goals", txtSmartGoal.Text)
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@Notes", txtNotes.Text)


            .ExecuteNonQuery()
        End With

    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)


    End Try
    newScoreConn.Close()


End Sub
```

Comment: `AddWithValue` leaves the DB Provider to guess what the datatype is, use `Add()` instead.  With OleDb you have to supply the parameters in the same exact order as they appear in the SQL.  Date and Time are being passed as those RB bools (also no need to split Date and Time nor pass them as text!)

Comment: please ignore the date/time portion as those are designed that way for a reason. can you please expand on the Add() portion of your answer, when I change to .Parameters.Add("@OneonOne", radioOne.Checked) I get error: 'Public Function Add(parameterName As String, value As Object) As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbParameter' is obsolete: 'Add(String parameterName, Object value) has been deprecated.  Use AddWithValue(String parameterName, Object value).

Comment: There is never a good reason to store Dates as Text - it is the source of may problems and oodles of SO questions,  `Add` has a number of overloads: `cmd.Parameters.Add("@dt, OleDbType.Date).Value = DateTimePicker132.Value` as you can see, the code tells OleDb what type is being passed.  Also since you dont specify the columns in the query, it may be luck if all the data gets mapped to the right db columns.  The db wont know where to put the data unless you tell it.

Comment: I will definitely look into changing the date format to the one you provided however I am still getting an error when I try to set up as follows:cmd.Parameters.Add("@OneonOne", OleDbType.Boolean).Value = radioOne.Checked

Comment: You have more than one thing wrong - in addition to using Add, you need to add them in **the same exact order as they appear in the SQL** with OleDb - see the first comment; then re-read the last one: you are not controlling which DB columns those values map to.  No idea *which* error, but the order will cause the mismatch.

Comment: Okay I see my error here and was able to correct however now Boolean insertion coming through as -1 instead of 1, any thoughts?

Comment: I am not sure what `coming through as -1` means.  Saved as an integer? `AddWithValue` will do that since the integer value of VB True is -1.  Cant see the code for the new problem, so anything else would be a WAG.